# API that uses selenium for webscraping

Tags: django, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm creating an API (Django/DRF with daphne) that accepts requests, scrapes website for data and returns it in response to user.

Will this work properly for multiple users in the same time (in parallel)? Or it's impossible to scrape website for each request at the same time?

Comment: It is possible 100%, its just a matter of implementation.

Comment: @AlexKaramfilov could you than suggest how / put me on the "right path"?

Comment: Check this article for more details: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/parallel-processing-python/ and this:https://www.anyscale.com/blog/parallelizing-python-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends

if multiple users scrape same website at the same time, and your scraping scripts without proxy, some user(s) may got errors response when the target website refuse to response to your process.

otherwise, it could work fine